# How to plot variables of each groupby group

Tags: python, pandas, plot, group-by, bar-chart

I have a DataFrame with colnames = ['cuit', 'nivel_0', 'nivel_1', 'nivel_2']). The 'nivel_...' columns are differente levels of aggregation for different types of industries. Such as: Durable Manufacturing (nivel_2) >> Computers (nivel_1) >> Laptops (nivel_0). All of them are `objects` dtypes.

I made a groupby for 'nivel_2' and a barplot using Seaborn.

```
barplot=df.groupby('nivel_2')['nivel_2'].agg('nivel_2':'count')

#Bar Plot: Number of Companies by Types of Industries (level 2 of aggregation)
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax=sns.barplot(barplot.index,barplot.values)
plt.title('Number of Companies by Types of Industries (level 2 of aggregation)')
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
```

I want for each group of `df.groupby('nivel_2')['nivel_2'].agg('nivel_2':'count')` get the group and plot them for the 'nivel_1' variable. All in the same code line. I have two many unique values for both 'nivel_2' and 'nivel_1' variables.

Any suggests?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Are you trying to plot the number of companies inside each different `nivel`?

Comment: Yeah, it seems i can't express myself. Watch at this example. For any particular row, i could have something like this: 34546687068 >> Durable Manufacturing >> Computers  >> Laptops. The colnames = ['id', 'level_2', 'level_1', 'level_0']. The level_2 is the level of more aggregattion, that's means that the type of industry Durable Manufacturing includes diferentes sub-types of industria like Computer manufacturera, and them includes the ones that makes laptops. With df.groupby('nivel_2')['nivel_2'].agg('nivel_2':'count'), i get the data to make a plot only for the level_2 of aggregattion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do:

```
ax = df['nivel_2'].avlue_counts().plot.bar()

# other plot/format commands
```